# Hibernate Zero to One unidirectional with reverse primary foreign key cascade

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm facing a problem with Hibernate in Spring Boot.

We have 2 tables, `users` and `user_info`, with a Zero To One (so a nullable One To One) relation.
The `user_info` has a primary foreign key that points to `users.user_id`:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `user_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  ...
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) 

CREATE TABLE `users_info` (
  `user_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `surname` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `mail` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  ...
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
  KEY `fk_user_id_idx` (`user_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_user_id` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) 
    REFERENCES `users` (`user_id`) 
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
)
```

And these are the models:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User implements UserDetails, Buildable<User.Builder> {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Long id;

    private String username;

    @Nullable
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
    @JsonUnwrapped
    private UserInfo userInfo;


    ...
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "users_info")
public class UserInfo {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Long id;

    @Nullable
    private String name;

    @Nullable
    private String surname;

    ...
}
```

When I run the Spring application with this configuration, it throws an error saying:

```
org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save()
```

How can we cascade-persist the `UserInfo` instance if not null from the User entity?

Thanks for the answer(s)!

Comment: show your save method

Comment: we are using an auto generated JpaRepository implementation, and the entity manager's `persist` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mapping is backwards. UserInfo should reference the user it's attached to, and be the owner of the association. And you should also say that its ID is also a foreign key to the user.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User implements UserDetails, Buildable<User.Builder> {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Long id;

    private String username;

    @Nullable
    @OneToOne(mappedBy="user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonUnwrapped
    private UserInfo userInfo;


    ...
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "users_info")
public class UserInfo {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Long id;

    @Nullable
    private String name;

    @Nullable
    private String surname;

    @OneToOne
    @MapsId
    private User user;
    ...
```

Comment: Tried with your solution, but it throws:

`org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: attempted to assign id from null one-to-one property [x.y.model.UserInfo.user]; nested exception is org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: attempted to assign id from null one-to-one property [x.y.model.UserInfo.user]`

Comment: Yo need to assign both sides (and especially, the owner side) of the association: userInfo.setUser(user).

Comment: Your answer is correct, but I had also to add the @JoinColumn(name="user_id") annotation on UserInfo.user. Thanks!